# Filtering a WFS layer using a shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wfs, filter

I want to perform a spatial filter on a WFS service (QGIS) so that I can only see the elements that correspond to my work area.
The layer doesn't have any spatial IDs, which would make it much easier, so I'm pretty lost.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. In order to get the best answer possible you need to provide as much information as possible about what you have tried and where you are stuck. Single sentence Questions are likely to be closed as *needing details*.

Comment: May I ask what you mean when you refer to 'spatial IDs'? The spatial component is the geometry. Are you able to share a link of the WFS, or is it private?